# Do I need to explicitely call con.close() after having done con.execute in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Suppose we have this code:

```
def _te(tn: str, db_id: str) -> bool:
    with _connect_db(db_id) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?", (tn,))
        
        return cur.fetchone()[0] == 1


def _connect_db(db_id: str) -> sqlite3.Connection:
    return sqlite3.connect(db_id)
```

Do I need to call close at the end of `_te`?

I found information that seems contradictory at my level of understanding:

On one hand, this accepted answer says (with a link to SQLite3 source code):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25988110/9661990

> You don't need to worry about closing the database. When you call prepare or execute, those calls are automatically call close when they are done. There is an internal rescue/ensure block that ensures the db is closed even if an error is raised. You can see this in the source code for SQLite3::Database.

But on the other hand, this SQLite3 doc:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

has a snippet with `execute`, and yet in this snippet it specifically commands a manual `close`:

```
# Create and fill the table.
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("CREATE TABLE lang(name, first_appeared)")
data = [
    ("C++", 1985),
    ("Objective-C", 1984),
]
con.executemany("INSERT INTO lang(name, first_appeared) VALUES(?, ?)", data)

# Print the table contents
for row in con.execute("SELECT name, first_appeared FROM lang"):
    print(row)

print("I just deleted", con.execute("DELETE FROM lang").rowcount, "rows")

# close() is not a shortcut method and it's not called automatically;
# the connection object should be closed manually
con.close()
```

Comment: no ou don't need to close the connection but it is recommended

Comment: You are using a `with`.  That will close the connection when the `with` block exits.

Comment: See [How to use the Connection context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-the-connection-context-manager)

Comment: The accepted answer you cite is just wrong. As the comment there says, `prepare` (and consequently also `execute`, which calls `prepare`) creates a statement, and ensures _the statement_ is closed at exit. It would be very bad if _the connection_ was closed after every `execute`.

Comment: @Amadan so, I do need to close manually, correct? Both for read and write operations? Does the presence of `with` matter? Thank you

Comment: @MarkTolonen it says `Note The context manager neither implicitly opens a new transaction nor closes the connection. If you need a closing context manager, consider using contextlib.closing().`, so in my case I do need to explicitely use the `close` call unless I am using `contextlib.closing()`, correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right. I should’ve read the link more closely. It is counterintuitive to the use of with though and not surprising that many get it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two (*) things that close the SQLite3 connection are the `.close()` method, and deallocating the connection object (which will happen some time after the connection object goes out of scope, and definitely at normal exit of Python if not before). As you noted, `with connection` will only commit or rollback at exit, not close the connection.

Exiting abnormally, e.g. by using `os._exit`, getting SIGKILLed, or computer shutting off, does not close the connection. See [Is it possible to lose data if a sqlite DB is not closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238866/is-it-possible-to-lose-data-if-a-sqlite-db-is-not-closed); you can also see [this description](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) of what happens during `sqlite3_close_v2`, which is used by `.close()` (in addition to freeing any resources taken up by the Python object itself).

Ideally, your program will use a limited amount of connections, most often just one. It is usually okay to not close the connections explicitly, as they will be closed automatically when the program exits (barring the scenarios above). It is still a good practice to do so though.

However, if you are opening connections in a loop (though I can't think of a scenario where that's a good idea), you must close them explicitly, or risk starving your computer of resources. Each connection takes up some memory, and a file descriptor; and both of those are in limited supply.

---

(*) The connection is also closed when calling `.__init__()` on an already open connection, but that is not really important.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure I understand the context correctly: Nicolai's answer is incorrect, right? I found this blog discussion here: https://blog.rtwilson.com/a-python-sqlite3-context-manager-gotcha/ , and it seems, according to it (and you - if I understand you correctly), that the context manager will NOT handle this for me, but Nicolai's answer already has 2 upvotes in just a few minutes, so I want to double check I am not misunderstanding anything. Thanks.

Comment: It is an easy mistake to make, since most `with foo.open()` and `with foo.connect()` will typically do a `foo.close()` at exit. SQLite3 does not. You can check yourself that [`pysqlite_connection_exit_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L2215) does not call `connection_close`, the way `pysqlite_connection_close_impl`, `connection_dealloc` and `pysqlite_connection_init_impl` do.

Comment: Thank you. Literally half the sources I found claim that context manager does handle it. Goes to show how widespread misconceptions can be even among skilled demographics.